# pip install x no longer working after upgrading pip?

Tags: python, cmd, pip, pypi

I have recently upgraded to the latest version of pip and this changed the behaviour of my pip installer.

Where before I could simply input `pip install requests` I now have to write `python -m pip install requests`, otherwise the following error happens:

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\xxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe"  "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe" install requests': The system cannot find the file specified.

I am running Python 3.8 so I'm not sure why pip is looking for Python 3.9.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
"c:\users\xxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe" 
"C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe"
```

from PATH, and add

```
"c:\users\xxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe" 
"C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\pip.exe"
```

instead.

Comment: The name of the program shouldn't be in the path.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that though. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @CyberPunkMetalHead Ok. I'd say this is a good guide to PATH https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/ . It will tell you how to edit PATH, add to PATH, e.t.c.